# Logging Common Table Expressions / CTE /WITH satements in Postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, logging, common-table-expression

I'm writing some queries using the WITH statement (common table expression approach) and would like to log the SQL in the back end log files.  I have the following logging enabled:

Postgresql version 13

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector='on'
log_directory = 'log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_statement = 'all'
```

But any SQL starting with WITH is not showing up at all, although standard SELECT statements show up fine.

Sample statement that is not being logged:

```
with 
table_a as (select 1+1 as total),
table_b as (select 2+2 as total),
table_c as (select 3+3 total)
select a.total*b.total* c.total
from table_a as a, table_b as b, table_c as c;
```

Is there a way to log these CTE statements as well?

thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  Did you reload the server after the `postgresql.conf` change? Are you sure you are looking at correct log?

Comment: Works for me.  Is the tool you are using to inspect the log file correctly dealing with csv records containing embedded newlines?

Comment: Thanks Adrian and jjanes - the problem was that I wasn't using a useful CSV viewer to look at the fine detail - the logs were there, just hidden in multi-line format (opening the file in sublime showed everything I was expecting).  

(Happy to give credit for the correct answer if you post it as an answer)